# Unable to show div from ng show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a new bee in angularjs and i get problem to show div through angularjs. However value are changed in subheaddiv(index) function but do not reflect in html.

Html Snipped:-

```
 <div ng-repeat="details in feeHeadDetails">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
        {{details.name}}
             <div ng-show="{{details.add}}">
                  <div ng-click="**subheaddiv($index)**" class="pull-right">
                   <div class="col-xs-12">
                       <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add Sub Head</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
               <div ng-show="{{details.deletable}}" class="pull-right">
                 <div class="col-xs-12">
                     <button headid="{{details.id}}" ng-click="deleteHead($event, $index)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                       </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
           </h4>
```

Angular Script:

```
 $scope.subheaddiv = function (index) {
   $scope.feeHeadDetails[index].add = false;
   $scope.feeHeadDetails[index].save = true;
   console.log($scope.feeHeadDetails[index]);
 };
```

Comment: you don't have to apply the {{}} when using ng-show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove braces:

```
ng-show="details.add"
ng-show="details.deletable"
```

Comment: yes! that's problem..thanks..@demidas,for quick response and save my time.

Answer (score 2):

From **[Ng Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)**

> The ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on
>   the expression provided to the ngShow attribute.

For ng-show / ng-hide / ng-if, you can use the model expression itself instead of `{{}}`

```
 <div ng-show="details.add">
```